# I have an issue with ${name} thing, how do i construct it?

Tags: javascript

This is the code:

```
function greetings(input){
let name = input.shift();
console.log('Hello, ${name}!');
}
greetings(["Niki"]);
```

Where is the issue, because by the given example it is written the same way and the exit code is:

```
Hello,  ${name}!
```

How do I type the code to actually write a name?

Comment: Use backticks ` instead of quotes ' to make it a template string.

Comment: You need to use backsticks ` instead of quotes.

Comment: A good idea, when encountering such issues (basic functionality of a language feature not working, expected cause always being a simple mistake/misunderstanding), is to copy&paste an example from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), identically, and see if it works. If it does, iteratively change the code, towards the own, non-working version, until it stops working. Then look what change made it fail.

Answer (score 2):

For the code to work you need to use the backtick character - ` instead of `'` or `"`.

Example:

```
function greetings(input){
let name = input.shift();
console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
}
greetings(["Niki"]);
```